Classical register initialization in Qiskit
I'm working on a qiskit code. Is there a way to initialize and change value of a classical register without a measurement from a quantum register?
At the moment I just initialize additional quantum register and then perform measurement to a classical register. This however, increases number of qubits in a circuit and makes simulations slower.
I need classical register to control gates in a part of my code.
